# Improving question quality by requiring "what have you tried?"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

I am here today to ask for a monumental change.

- A section that asks the user what they have tried

I feel that question quality could improve dramatically and members can help others faster, rather than waiting for the OP to post what they have tried or what system/language they are using. I would like to propose a required section on the **Ask Question** form that, if the question is programming related, requires the OP to post code of what they have tried. As a topping, could the tag section expand with "include the system or language your using?"

This would alleviate the need to comment, **"What have you tried?"**. I assume it would significantly decrease the number of low quality post flags, allowing moderators to focus their energy elsewhere.

This is a very basic mock-up of what I would love to see:

[image]

Comment: That, it a **much** better idea than my, and I quote, _"Pester Screen of Death"_. Would you require someone to fill it in?

Comment: While I like the idea, I feel that not all questions can be shoe-horned into this format. Specifically, many of the questions that ask for a "why" or a "which" tend to be less applicable to this.

Comment: @Ben There needs to be a mechanism in place that requires the user to enter what they have tried. I feel a pop-up or on-screen message would be ignored.

Comment: That wasn't my question. What would happen if a user completely ignores this new box?

Comment: @Mysticial I agree. If we can determine whether it is a programming question, then the WHYT section would be required.

Comment: Assuming it is optional, the mere presence of such a field might be a gentle nudge to provide the information.  Making it required probably will not work since there are some acceptable questions, as @Mysticial has said, that do not have a "what have you tried" type response.  But I do like the idea

Comment: @Ben My apologies, didn't finish reading your comment. If it is a programming question, it should be required. Perhaps penalize the user for not using the box?

Comment: @njk The point I was saying is that not all programming questions have a "what have you tried" type response.

Comment: I'm not certain about "penalise" as @Mysticial has pointed out not everything has code. However, an idea might be to automatically shovel it into the low quality question queue if somebody doesn't use the box.

Comment: @Mysticial Agreed. I should have been more clear on that.

Comment: "What have you tried?" *<insert wall of code here>*

Comment: Instead of an additional input form element, wouldn't it be enough to add [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) right after "what's your programming question? be specific."?

Comment: @BilltheLizard What are the chances a novice will bother reading it?

Comment: I get the feeling that if the OP doesn't bother to read obnoxious popups, then the question has a good chance of being crap anyways.

Comment: Probably not as good as the chances that they'll just leave because we've added too many form elements.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I still feel that as a developer, just the mention of including "What have you tried" gives them a push towards better practice. I think requiring this on SO would have a positive effect.

Comment: I'm probably in the minority here, but I don't like that SO is turning into personal debugging service. This would just make it official.

Comment: @Juhana How do you then improve the quality of questions or enforce the idea that is not a personal debugging service?

Comment: @njk I wish I had the answer to that.

Comment: @Juhana I certainly don't feel that it's a debugging service. I see SO as a place for beginners to get help from individuals that have a passion for programming. Just [last night I saw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361521/mysql-column-wise-category-counting/) an individual answer a question on a -5 question just because he felt it might revive it.

Comment: I'm not sure about this... But that single-item list on your question really bothers me! :)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I feel compelled to point out that you're only rotating the name, not turning it backwards ..

Comment: It's been done before @jcolebrand :). I think my excuse last time is that it is to confuse and disoriented my enemies, to stop them from finding me... I just like a little misdirection sometimes, I guess.