# Should I delete my question having down votes because the problem was a simple mistake, but with some useful stuff?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Sometimes when I ask a question, I try to provide some basics so that some people can get some help reading my question. Sometimes someone points to me that I have made a simple mistake, that's why I raised the question and soon I get some downvotes for my question. But I still think I gave some information worth reading to others (because the info I added in my question are what I looked for some time ago) in my original question. In this case, should I delete my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might depend on the specific Stack Exchange site you're on, but in general:

- if you can improve your question so that it's *useful for future readers*, please do so and leave the question undeleted.
- if you can't (so it's only useful for you, and you fixed your problem), it's better just to delete it.

Remember, the [main goal of Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217136/295232) is

> ... to help the most people we can.

And deleting your post (if it's only useful for you) helps in this by providing less distraction to future visitors.

Comment: It's not necessarily better to delete it if there's already value in the question/answers.

Comment: Value for *future readers*, yes. I know this can be sometimes hard to determine.