# Flagging variations on "what have you tried"

Tags: discussion, comments

This is in relation to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459217/regex-for-extracting-a-string-that-contains-a-string-and-is-between-2-strings/19459254#19459254), and I saw the comment

> What is the current regular expression used, and how does it not work as expected?

Which might be a good comment in some cases, but the question did not mention a current regular expression, and did not mention that there was any problem with it.

All I saw was a disguised version of

> What have you tried?

Now, I want to flag this comment as not constructive, mostly because I deeply hate `what have you tried?` comments.

But I'm afraid that a moderator will come along, and be fooled by the disguise on the `what have you tried`, and reject the flag.

---

My question is, If a comment doesn't **mean** anything beyond `What have you tried?` should I flag it?

Comment: Whether it's "disguised" or not, why is that not a good question to ask the OP?

Comment: @DavidRobinson because it's dismissive, and very rarely describes what the commenter really thinks is missing.

Comment: The question you linked to is the problem, not the comment.

Comment: @BilltheLizard they're both problems

Comment: The comment is perfectly reasonable, given the question.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with "What have you tried" comments isn't that they're asking the OP what he tried- that's the last thing we should be discouraging. The problem (as discussed in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic)) is that it's snarky and dismissive, that it's not specific to the user's question, and that duplicates tend to build up because commenters leave them without thinking. Ironically for a comment meant to point out a lack of effort, it shows no effort on the part of the commenter.

Asking what a user has tried in a way that is specific to his question and encourages a response (see that the OP does respond with his attempt) is a great behavior- we shouldn't punish it just because of a history of *other* users asking rudely.

Comment: the same thing happened in this case that that happened in the past.  The user told us what he tried, and unsurprisingly, it was wrong, and it wasn't exactly useful to anyone who wanted to compose an actual solution.