# New comment flag - "Too sarcastic"

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-flags

Can we have a new flag for comments - "Too sarcastic"?

Look at this question, for example, and the first comment: [Compare textbox text with sql server name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762962/compare-textbox-text-with-sql-server-name). PO is new, looks like a beginner programmer. True, the question is trivial and the answer is all over the internet, but is there a need for that much sarcasm?

So can we have the new flag?

This question is only partially a joke.

The comment has since been flagged as Martijn advised and has been deleted.

Comment: That's what 'not constructive' is for. Also, dinner with Megan Fox, who can blame him?!

Comment: Is it really? Let's see if it will work.

Comment: There is no such thing as too sarcastic....

Comment: Somehow I think people who "want" something deserve such sarcastic remarks

Comment: If a comment consists of little more than "what have you tried" (other comments such as "show me your code" _are_ different), flag as "not constructive".

Comment: Seriously though, I kind of get what you mean. But I think it actually is constructive, phrased with some humour. This is no worse than the hundreds of *what have you tried* comments that appear every day. At least he's put a bit of effort into this on?!

Comment: @Liam: yet being sarcastic a comment about sarcasm which is sarcastic in itself which is on a post about a comment that is sarcastic is rather ironic.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["What have you tried" epidemic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic)

Comment: If we add this we need to add "Too short", "Too long", "Too nice" and 100 more.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, if that trend were to continue the universe would probably unravel.....

Comment: This is the most brilliant feature request ever made.  Ever.  Made.

Comment: @Won't Now we need a "not enough sarcasm" flag.  Sorry, but that post just isn't far enough over the line.

Comment: @Servy, come one, why remove the last line?

Comment: @Szymon 1) You couldn't remove the question even if you wanted to; it has an upvoted answer 2) It's a meta commentary on the post, you can put it in a comment if you want, but the question should be where you ask the question, rather than talk about not deleting the question or how many votes it has.  3) You're at -20.  ;) That's the problem with such comments, they get out of date.

Comment: @Servy True, true. I'll play nice from now on :)

Comment: @Szymon Meta is a bit more informal, but that informality is *mostly* for comments.  I admit the culture is very hard to get though.  By and large, both questions and answers should be fairly serious.  (Unless the entire q/a is all one big joke.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning how things work here. Haven't been around for too long...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the option "too chatty" covers the area of "too sarcastic".

In the link you provided though, I'd use "not constructive".

Comment: Sarcasm is usually fairly rude and/or offensive (i.e. that reason may be better suited).