# Comment can't contain that content

Tags: support, comments

I posted a comment to a low effort question here: [I want to grab href address which has class link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133564/i-want-to-grab-href-address-which-has-class-link)

I typed too fast and it came out like

> "What you tried?"

I tried to edit it to

> "What have you tried?"

and got "Comments can't contain that content."

Comment: Basically, there was a big controversy over people commenting that, [so it got banned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/223030).

Comment: That's because comments can't contain that content. I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: I didn't know that was a banned comment, problem solved.

Comment: It arguably could have a clearer message

Comment: Don't use "what you tried so far" or similar (like "show your work"). Instead, describe the specific issues with the question and how the user should go about fixing these issues.