# QuickComments as 'What have you tried?' and 'What is your question?'

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes we encounter questions that don't have a 'Question' in 
them and other times we get question but no code or any idea if the 
user tried anything or not. For that reason, moderators and others 
can flag the question.

But I propose if there was a small link like 'QuickComments' or 
something similar, and it had template messages like 'What have you 
tried?', 'What is your Question Exactly?' and clicking on those 
would show a highlighted div box that shows the concern and names of 
users who raised it. This would save both time and effort of the 
users.

[image]

Update: I know about 'What have you tried?' being blocked. I looked at that question and got the idea of this proposal. The point I am trying to make is the reason why these comments were block was it took too much space and flooded the comment area with same comments. If one common comment could be highlighted and anyone with similar concern could just mark it, it would solve the issue. Also we can't just totally get rid of this question as people do ask questions that must be countered with 'What have you tried?' or 'What is your Question?'.

Comment: Seems like another layer of hassle that could just be done by normal commenting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### "What have you tried" is **explicitly blocked**

> Starting now, comments that consist of nothing but "what have you tried" are blocked completely, and comments that consist of little more than "what have you tried" can be deleted with a single flag.

See the link below for the discussion on why comments like this are not welcome.

Source answer to ["What have you tried" epidemic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic) by [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)

---

#### But people do ask questions that must be countered with 'What have you tried?' or 'What is your Question?'.

You already have the options of:

1. Downvoting and Flagging as "unclear what you are asking" or "too broad"
2. Leaving a more useful comment, for example

   > Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Comment: @SorrelVesper Please see updated answer.

Comment: Okay. That's a fair point. This may be an extra layer of hassle. So. Okay. Please request to close the question. Thank you.