# Regex pattern for automatic removal of "what have you tried"

Tags: feature-request, support, comment-flags

According to ["What have you tried" epidemic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/259305), this four-word question has been banned from comments, and "comments that consist of *little more* than "what have you tried" can be deleted with a single flag."

I had flagged several comments starting with "what have you tried", and they were *instantly* removed after the comment flag submission.

However, my flag on this ["but what have you tried"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116349/dfm-ab-and-ba#comment6420917_3116349) comment was still pending for five hours before being deleted.

Can the regex matching pattern be improved so that comments like this can also be removed immediately with a single flag?

---

Edit: I'm *not* in the IT sector.  The only thing that I have in mind is `.*what have you tried.*`.  The lack of this regex doesn't undermine the need to delete comments consisting of little more than this four word question.

Comment: I'd rather see the regex gone entirely ... but that's none of my business.

Comment: Could you please tell us what have you tried to come up with a regex?

Comment: Looks like that comment is gone now. What was it?

Comment: @Draco18s I flagged it and it was removed automatically since it's unhelpful.

Comment: ʷⒽ@Ⓣ Αᵥᵉ Øμ îε?

Comment: @Mysticial Don't you see my [edit] to this post?  I've already included a regex pattern.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I'm saying regex filtering is stupid because it's easily defeated.

Comment: No, what I meant was, you said that it *wasn't* removed automatically. Or, at least, not instantly. The whole point of your question. Whatever you were complaining about necessitating a change in the regex.

Comment: @Draco18s The system recognises that four word question at the beginning, but if it's prepended with one word, then the automatic removal doesn't happen.  However, the act of left-prepending only adds "little more" to that four word question, so it suits the criteria for automatic removal in the linked meta post.  As a Math.SE user, I'm used to logical thinking from established results, and I don't get why it *doesn't* get automatically deleted.

Comment: `but if it's prepended with one word` Ah! That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're asking but it should only be set to auto-delete exactly that phrase when it exists on its own because that phrase can exist in a proper response. It should also not delete any reply that begins with the phrase but has anything extra on the end. Granted these are easily abused, but it comes down to a choice between preventing abuse and possibly losing legitimate replies or allowing a little legroom and not losing anything potentially helpful.
Rules should only be applied to the absolute minimum possible.

Suppose someone asked a question and the reply responds with the answer but is also offering to help the person see what they were doing wrong or help them on a different thing they were trying, it could easily look something like:

> "I want to block routing within my switches but only for specific
>   vlans, but it doesn't seem to be working, what's something simple I can use to block traffic between vlans"

Then the reply comes in

> "ACLs, what have you tried?"

Here a rule stating that adding "a little more" to the phrase should also be deleted would probably lead the rule to delete this reply which did in fact give a proper response but foolishly used a phrase that has caused issues/concerns in the past.

Keeping it to only delete a reply that matches that specific phrase means that you know exactly what you're deleting and will never accidentally delete a reply that was actually trying to be helpful.
The rule should be "delete exact matches, flag possible transgressions"
Then later (maybe your 5 hours) someone can check it, and say, "yeah, let's delete that" or "ah, that looks ok, let's not delete that one"